# asynctask returning null on hero 2.1

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm a newbie so bear with me.

I have a asynctask that pulls the closest locations near me from a web service. It works fine on a newer android device greater than 2.1. I have a HTC hero with 2.1 and it crashes every time I press the button to find the data.

Here is the code that I have. The first part gets the lat and long from the device and sends it to a php script that I created on the server.

```
    private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat", lat));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("long", longit));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                        HTTP.UTF_8);
                httppost.setEntity(ent);
                HttpResponse responsePOST = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(responsePOST.getEntity());
                Log.i("YAhh", responseBody);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }
        return responseBody;
        }
```

This part sends the data to another activity to be parsed and displayed in a listview.

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("returndata",responseBody);
    /*  Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,
                locationActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("returnBody", responseBody);
        bundle.putString("latit", lat);
        bundle.putString("longit" + "", longit);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);*/
    }
}
```

This is the error that I am receiving, from what I can tell there is no data being returned so the null value is causing the error.

```
  08-02 15:17:13.848: E/AndroidRuntime(1117): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught   exception
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at android.util.Log.println(Native Method)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:136)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at com.mlgw.mlgwapp.HomeActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.onPostExecute(HomeActivity.java:278)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at   com.mlgw.mlgwapp.HomeActivity$DownloadWebPageTask.onPostExecute(HomeActivity.java:1)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4595)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
  08-02 15:17:13.968: E/AndroidRuntime(1117):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anybody have a clue as to why this isn't working on 2.1?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where responseBody  is declared?

Comment: It is very difficult to tell what is going on since you catch and then do nothing with any exceptions that are being thrown.  So, it is not clear if there is a problem with the call perhaps.  At least log a message that there was an exception and see if that shows up.

Comment: After doing a e.printStackTrace it seems 2.1 does not like https once I changed it to Http it ran. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to put a `Log.w()` or a `printStackTrace()` into thouse exceptions:

```
   } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
 return responseBody;
 }
```

The you can use `logcat` to see what causes them.

This method `onPostExecute` looks suspicious. Replace `responseBody` with `result`:

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         Log.i("returndata",result);

    }
```

Comment: After doing a e.printStackTrace it seems 2.1 does not like https once I changed it to Http it ran. Any thoughts?

Comment: Most likely an issue with the Server certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You used async task in a wrong way.

First, where is `responseBody` declared?
Make sure its not null!!

Also the other error is that:
you return `responseBody`, in doInBackground.
That return string, is the `result`, in  `onPostExecute` method.

So on `onPostExecute` replace `responseBody` with `result`
..

```
  Log.i("returndata",result);
```

..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have responseBody declared as a string, I also made the change you requested but I still get the same error on my hero. It runs on my other phones.